# How to map dictionary with dynamic keys with ObjectMapper?

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

I'm new to ObjectMapper. I have response from the server:

```
{
      "123123": 10,
      "435555": 2,
      "435333": 8,
      "567567": 4
}
```

Keys (dynamic) are going to be IDs. Values are going to be COUNT. How can I map it with ObjectMapper?

My code isn't working because dynamic keys:

```
extension Item: Mappable {

    private static let kId = "id"
    private static let kCount = "count"

    public init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    mutating public func mapping(map: Map) {

        id <- map[Item.kId]
        count <- map[Item.kCount]
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel, ObjectMapper won't be able to help you as it will be dynamic Ids. Why can't you create custom class/struct/simple dictionary for this case.

Answer (score 3):

Your response is an object and you can access it via `map.JSON`, and its type is `[String: Any]`. Then you can use that like a normal `Dictionary`.

Here I create a class named `Model` that has array of items (of type `Item`) and in `func mapping(:Map)` I mapped `map.JSON` elements to `Item`.

```swift
class Model: Mappable {
    typealias Item = (id: String, count: Int)
    var items: [Item] = []

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        let rawDictionary = map.JSON
        let items = rawDictionary.compactMap { (key, value) -> Item? in
            guard let intValue = value as? Int else { return nil }
            return (key, intValue)
        }
        self.items = items
    }
}

let jsonString = """
{
    "123123": 10,
    "435555": 2,
    "435333": 8,
    "567567": 4
}
"""

let model = Model(JSONString: jsonString)
print(model?.items[0])  //Optional((id: "123123", count: 10))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
 do{

    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:Int].self, from: data)

}
catch {

    print(error)
}
```